# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException in Kentico cloud

Tags: kentico-kontent

I have done a simple code to retrieve published content from Kentico cloud.I am using Inbuilt classes/Code given by Kentico cloud to retrieve. While retrieving I am getting the following exception.

```
"timestamp": "2019-07-15T14:05:11.645+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",

    "message": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field \"width\" (class com.kenticocloud.delivery.Image), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: \"description\", \"image_id\", \"url\"])\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.kenticocloud.delivery.ContentItemsListingResponse[\"items\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.kenticocloud.delivery.ContentItem[\"elements\"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap[\"section\"]->com.kenticocloud.delivery.RichTextElement[\"images\"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap[\"dd2f48ec-252a-41b9-badf-320c8d125c16\"]->com.kenticocloud.delivery.Image[\"width\"])",
```

It is happening due to unrecognized property in the Json Response. This is the unexpected reponse I am getting.

```
"leader_image": {
                    "type": "asset",
                    "name": "Leader Image",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "name": "KemperKip_Rabobank_header.jpg",
                            "description": null,
                            "type": "image/jpeg",
                            "size": 500407,
                            "url": "https://assets-us-01.kc-usercontent.com:443/c6e7ef22-97ac-008a-8a75-a65bfc508501/4ecbfb36-60a6-49c7-a4a1-e8c5ad964a9a/KemperKip_Rabobank_header.jpg",
                            "width": 3348,
                            "height": 1874
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Here `width` and `height` parameters are not mentioned in the mapping class.

I am using the following code snippets from Kentico cloud site DeliveryClient client = new DeliveryClient("975bf280-fd91-488c-994c-2f04416e5ee3", ""); 
ContentItem item = client.getItem("on_roasts").item;

Can you please provide the updated maven dependency version.I am using this version

com.kenticocloud delivery 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using direct call without using the SDK.

The image resolution [was added to the delivery response on April 24th, 2019](https://docs.kenticocloud.com/reference/api-changelog#a-image-resolution-in-delivery-api).

With this enhancement, you can, for example, render placeholders for images in your application before the assets themselves are loaded.

Comment: I can't get your point 'I assume you are using direct call without using the SDK'.I am using the following code snippets from Kentico cloud site DeliveryClient client = new DeliveryClient("975bf280-fd91-488c-994c-2f04416e5ee3", "<YOUR_PREVIEW_API_KEY>");

ContentItem item = client.getItem("on_roasts").item;.Can you please provide the updated maven dependency version.I am using this version <dependency>
    <groupId>com.kenticocloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>delivery</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Ahh ok I see - you are using [Java SDK](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-java) - the problem is that dimensions are currently not declared in the [Asset model](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-java/blob/master/delivery/src/main/java/com/kenticocloud/delivery/Asset.java)

I have submitted an [issue](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-java/issues/82) for that - you could keep track it there.